# Why do some of my static cells disappear from the simulator screen when I rotate the simulator to a landscape mode?

Tags: ios

I'm running through Apple's "Start Developing iOS Apps Today" lessons using Xcode 5.1.1. I'm doing the tutorial on storyboards, which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1).
I am currently in the section called "Display Static Content in a Table View." I have 13 cells set up in a table view controller and when I run the app in portrait mode I am able to scroll down and see them all, which is what I expect. However, when I go to Hardware and select Rotate Left or Rotate Right and switch to landscape mode, only the first 7 cells appear, and there is no way to scroll down to see the rest. Does anyone know how to keep all of the cells after rotating to landscape? As far as I can tell I have followed all of their instructions. The whole recursiveDescription can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxwuMYlD-wEaNGZwYU4wRFM5RTA/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: you should use a UITAbleViewController, and test on a real device

Comment: As far as I can tell I am using a UITableViewController (I dragged it out from the object library). Unfortunately I can't test on a real device yet because I don't have a paid developer account.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a problem with the auto layout constraints (or lack thereof, if you're using auto layout) or the resizing masks if you're not using auto layout.

You can confirm this diagnosis if you run the app through Xcode, rotate the screen, and then hit the "pause" button. Then, at the `(lldb)` prompt, type:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

You'll see a lengthy hierarchy of all of the views, and look at the `frame` of the table view and see if it makes sense for the current orientation.

Perhaps you can update your question with that output if you have a hard time interpreting the results.

For information on how to use auto layout, see the [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Here is what I found after following your instructions, although I'm not sure how to interpret it:   |    |    |    | <UITableView: 0xc93d200; frame = (0 0; 568 320); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc2c42a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xc2c2d80>; contentOffset: {0, -52}>

Comment: @jhonkaman The key piece of information is the `frame`, which actually looks OK. But, can you please edit your original question and include the full `recursiveDescription` output? It's going to be hard to follow in comments (and you'll have to cut it off prematurely, as comments limit how long they can be).